# How to add a text label to a line in a block diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm very new to LATEX and I'm trying to set a block diagram and at the same time format it exactly as I'd like, please see my block diagram below:

https://www.writelatex.com/1492096yphfwt#/3712155/

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\title{Analogue Synthesizer block diagram}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

%Define standard Block diagram node styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -stealth, thick]

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

% Blocks
\draw (2,1) node[block] (LFO) {LFO};
\draw (2,0) node[block] (VCO1) {VCO1};
\draw (4,0) node[block] (VCF) {VCF};
\draw (4,-1) node[block] (ADSR1) {ADSR};
\draw (6,0) node[block] (VCA) {VCA};
\draw (6,-1) node[block] (ADSR2) {ADSR};
\draw (0,-2) node[block] (Midi to CV) {MIDI to CV};
\draw (0,-3) node[block] (Keyboard) {MIDI Keyboard};

% Lines
\path[line] (LFO) -- (VCO1);
\path[line] (VCO1) -- (VCF);
\path[line] (VCF) -- (VCA);
\path[line] (ADSR1) -- (VCF);
\path[line] (ADSR2) -- (VCA);
\path[line] (Keyboard) -- (Midi to CV);
\path[line] (Midi to CV.north) |- node[yshift=-4em, xshift=0.5em,fill=white]{1V/Octave} (VCO1);
\path[line] (Midi to CV.east) -| node[yshift=0em, xshift=-4em,fill=white]{Gate} (ADSR1.south);
\path[line] (Midi to CV.east) -| node[yshift=0em, xshift=0em]{} (ADSR2.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: My block diagram output]

My specific issue relates to the text label **Gate**, as you can see I have lines connecting *MIDI to CV* with both *ADSR* blocks, as such I have a line running through **Gate**, and I want it formatted as the **1V/Octave** label.

It maybe that I need format the `\path[line]` differently; could anyone please help.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you please add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you. External links aren't very useful:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you first write the Gate label and you then draw another line over the top of it. If you just swap the last two lines in your `tikzpicture` environment  then you get what you want:

[image]

Here is your hacked code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}

\title{Analogue Synthesizer block diagram}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

%Define standard Block diagram node styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -stealth, thick]

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

  % Blocks
  \draw (2,1) node[block] (LFO) {LFO};
  \draw (2,0) node[block] (VCO1) {VCO1};
  \draw (4,0) node[block] (VCF) {VCF};
  \draw (4,-1) node[block] (ADSR1) {ADSR};
  \draw (6,0) node[block] (VCA) {VCA};
  \draw (6,-1) node[block] (ADSR2) {ADSR};
  \draw (0,-2) node[block] (Midi to CV) {MIDI to CV};
  \draw (0,-3) node[block] (Keyboard) {MIDI Keyboard};

  % Lines
  \path[line] (LFO) -- (VCO1);
  \path[line] (VCO1) -- (VCF);
  \path[line] (VCF) -- (VCA);
  \path[line] (ADSR1) -- (VCF);
  \path[line] (ADSR2) -- (VCA);
  \path[line] (Keyboard) -- (Midi to CV);
  \path[line] (Midi to CV.north) |- node[yshift=-4em, xshift=0.5em,fill=white]{1V/Octave} (VCO1);
  \path[line] (Midi to CV.east) -| node[yshift=0em, xshift=0em]{} (ADSR2.south);
  \path[line] (Midi to CV.east) -| node[yshift=0em, xshift=-4em,fill=white]{Gate} (ADSR1.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, that worked. Would you say the way I'm constructing this block diagram is correct, or would there be a better approach? Regards

Comment: @Alex2134 Yes, I think it's pretty good. Most people who are "very new to LATEX" wouldn't be defining their own tikz styles:)